# Show that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ if and only if $f$ is differentiable at $1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x/y) = f(x) - f(y)$ for all $x,y>0$ and that $f(1) = 0$.

Question: Show that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ if and only if $f$ is differentiable at $1$.

My attempt on this problem:

Let $a \in (0,\infty)$. Then $f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(\frac{a+h}{a})}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1 +\frac{h}{a})}{h}.$

All I know is that the top will go to $f(1) = 0$ and the bottom will also go to $0$ but I don't know how to show that this is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $f(1)=0$ would help you.

Comment: $ \frac {\frac {f(1+\frac ha)}a}{\frac ha}=\frac {f(1+\frac ha)}h$ This should also help

Comment: Thank you guys!

Comment: The value of $f(1)$ follows from putting $x=y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$,then $f$ is differentiable at $1$.

For the other direction, suppose $f$ is differentiable at $1$,i.e.$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1+h)-0}{h}$$ exists. Now let $a \in (0,\infty)$. Then 
\begin{align}
f'(a) &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}\\
& = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(\frac{a+h}{a})}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1 +\frac{h}{a})}{h}
\end{align}
Let  $u=\frac{h}{a}$. Then we have 
\begin{align}
f'(a) &=\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{f(1 +u)}{au}\\
&=\frac{f'(1)}{a}
\end{align}
Since  $a\neq 0$, $f'(a)$ exists.

Comment: Thank you so much!